# Sharepoint 2013 - video and image responsive carousel

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, sandbox-solution, apps-development

I am looking for some advice on a solution for a media carousel that is responsive and will hold and display video and images.

I have looked at various solutions over the web but they seem to fall short. I am Willing to develop a webpart if there is a solid solution example to follow or install a solution that has been developed and is solid.

Is there a way to create responsive image renditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best one I found is the solution provided by Share-gate here http://en.share-gate.com/blog/image-slider-with-sharepoint-2013-search-results

Basically it is based on using search results web part and custom display template. I have followed the same example on an intranet site I have built, but I was able to change from SlideJS to jssor sliders here http://www.jssor.com/demos/

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. I will try this out and see how it performs.

Comment: Ahmed - The example from Share-gate is good. I have it working well. In regards to the jssor version I will need to ask your advice. I have downloaded the source code - do I need to make new display templates? If so I will need a little more guidance. Thanks for the great recommendation.

Comment: well, yes...you need 2 display templates (one to be your control and one to be your item)...my advice is to dissect any slider from jssor and identify the outer div (parent div or container) and extract that and put it in the control display template and the actual slide div and put it in the item display template...

Comment: I am not fantastic with code - you wouldn't have an example?

Comment: I will attempt the 'Linkin'g example from the full width slider.

Comment: I will try to build one this weekend and pass it your way

Comment: Hi Ahmed - I am not having any luck developing this further - have you had any?

Comment: It's good but this is not considered a proper reply, as one of the links is not working already this might not be useful in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

You can try, [Owl Carousel](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/) plugin which supports responsive, and also videos. It can be used in Addin, Content Editor WebPart, and also in the display templates.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. I will see how this one performs in our environment

Comment: Rajesh - this is a beta version with well over 400 issues listed in GitHub. Have you tried it in SharePoint 2013 and have you had success?